# ffmpeg is not removing some seconds from the beginning of this video. Why and how can I make it do so?

Tags: video, ffmpeg

Why would ffmpeg not be removing some seconds from the beginning of this video?

video here http://ge.tt/2WsYqi63

```
C:\somedir>mediainfo blah.mp4
General
Complete name                            : blah.mp4
Format                                   : MPEG-4
Format profile                           : Base Media
Codec ID                                 : isom (isom/iso2/avc1/mp41)
File size                                : 1.77 MiB
Duration                                 : 18 s 693 ms
Overall bit rate mode                    : Variable
Overall bit rate                         : 796 kb/s
Encoded date                             : UTC 2020-08-27 22:50:08
Tagged date                              : UTC 2020-08-27 22:50:08
Writing application                      : Lavf51.12.1

Video
ID                                       : 1
Format                                   : AVC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Video Codec
Format profile                           : Main@L3
Format settings                          : CABAC / 3 Ref Frames
Format settings, CABAC                   : Yes
Format settings, Reference frames        : 3 frames
Codec ID                                 : avc1
Codec ID/Info                            : Advanced Video Coding
Duration                                 : 18 s 680 ms
Bit rate                                 : 666 kb/s
Width                                    : 852 pixels
Height                                   : 480 pixels
Display aspect ratio                     : 16:9
Frame rate mode                          : Constant
Frame rate                               : 25.000 FPS
Color space                              : YUV
Chroma subsampling                       : 4:2:0
Bit depth                                : 8 bits
Scan type                                : Progressive
Bits/(Pixel*Frame)                       : 0.065
Stream size                              : 1.48 MiB (84%)
Encoded date                             : UTC 2020-08-27 22:50:08
Tagged date                              : UTC 2020-08-27 22:50:08
Codec configuration box                  : avcC

Audio
ID                                       : 2
Format                                   : AAC LC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Audio Codec Low Complexity
Codec ID                                 : mp4a-40-2
Duration                                 : 18 s 693 ms
Bit rate mode                            : Variable
Bit rate                                 : 126 kb/s
Channel(s)                               : 2 channels
Channel layout                           : L R
Sampling rate                            : 44.1 kHz
Frame rate                               : 43.066 FPS (1024 SPF)
Compression mode                         : Lossy
Stream size                              : 287 KiB (16%)
Encoded date                             : UTC 2020-08-27 22:50:08
Tagged date                              : UTC 2020-08-27 22:50:08



C:\somedir>mediainfo blah.mp4 | find "Duration"
Duration                                 : 18 s 693 ms
Duration                                 : 18 s 680 ms
Duration                                 : 18 s 693 ms

C:\somedir>ffmpeg -ss 4 -i blah.mp4 -c copy blah2.mp4
ffmpeg version N-94664-g0821bc4eee Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 9.1.1 (GCC) 20190807
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libdav1d --e
nable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus -
-enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --ena
ble-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enabl
e-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enable-libspeex --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libmfx --enable-amf --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuvid
--enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-nvdec --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth --enable-libopenmpt
  libavutil      56. 33.100 / 56. 33.100
  libavcodec     58. 55.101 / 58. 55.101
  libavformat    58. 31.104 / 58. 31.104
  libavdevice    58.  9.100 / 58.  9.100
  libavfilter     7. 58.101 /  7. 58.101
  libswscale      5.  6.100 /  5.  6.100
  libswresample   3.  6.100 /  3.  6.100
  libpostproc    55.  6.100 / 55.  6.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'blah.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    creation_time   : 2020-08-27T22:50:08.000000Z
    encoder         : Lavf51.12.1
  Duration: 00:00:18.69, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 796 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 852x480 [SAR 1:1 DAR 71:40], 665 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 50 tbc (default)

    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2020-08-27T22:50:06.000000Z
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 125 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2020-08-27T22:50:06.000000Z
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
Output #0, mp4, to 'blah2.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.31.104
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 852x480 [SAR 1:1 DAR 71:40], q=2-31, 665 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 12800 tbn, 25 tb
c (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2020-08-27T22:50:06.000000Z
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 125 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2020-08-27T22:50:06.000000Z
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame=  467 fps=0.0 q=-1.0 Lsize=    1819kB time=00:00:14.66 bitrate=1015.9kbits/s speed=1.63e+03x
video:1518kB audio:287kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.821737%

C:\somedir>mediainfo blah2.mp4 | find "Duration"
Duration                                 : 18 s 693 ms
Duration                                 : 18 s 680 ms
Duration                                 : 18 s 693 ms

C:\somedir>mediainfo blah2.mp4
General
Complete name                            : blah2.mp4
Format                                   : MPEG-4
Format profile                           : Base Media
Codec ID                                 : isom (isom/iso2/avc1/mp41)
File size                                : 1.78 MiB
Duration                                 : 18 s 693 ms
Overall bit rate                         : 797 kb/s
Writing application                      : Lavf58.31.104

Video
ID                                       : 1
Format                                   : AVC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Video Codec
Format profile                           : Main@L3
Format settings                          : CABAC / 3 Ref Frames
Format settings, CABAC                   : Yes
Format settings, Reference frames        : 3 frames
Codec ID                                 : avc1
Codec ID/Info                            : Advanced Video Coding
Duration                                 : 18 s 680 ms
Bit rate                                 : 666 kb/s
Width                                    : 852 pixels
Height                                   : 480 pixels
Display aspect ratio                     : 16:9
Frame rate mode                          : Constant
Frame rate                               : 25.000 FPS
Color space                              : YUV
Chroma subsampling                       : 4:2:0
Bit depth                                : 8 bits
Scan type                                : Progressive
Bits/(Pixel*Frame)                       : 0.065
Stream size                              : 1.48 MiB (83%)
Codec configuration box                  : avcC

Audio
ID                                       : 2
Format                                   : AAC LC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Audio Codec Low Complexity
Codec ID                                 : mp4a-40-2
Duration                                 : 18 s 693 ms
Bit rate mode                            : Constant
Bit rate                                 : 126 kb/s
Channel(s)                               : 2 channels
Channel layout                           : L R
Sampling rate                            : 44.1 kHz
Frame rate                               : 43.066 FPS (1024 SPF)
Compression mode                         : Lossy
Stream size                              : 287 KiB (16%)
Default                                  : Yes
Alternate group                          : 1



C:\somedir>
```

so to summarise, we have

```
C:\somedir>mediainfo blah.mp4 | find "Duration"
Duration                                 : 18 s 693 ms
Duration                                 : 18 s 680 ms
Duration                                 : 18 s 693 ms

C:\somedir>ffmpeg -ss 4 -i blah.mp4 -c copy blah2.mp4

C:\somedir>mediainfo blah2.mp4 | find "Duration"
Duration                                 : 18 s 693 ms
Duration                                 : 18 s 680 ms
Duration                                 : 18 s 693 ms

C:\somedir>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use `-c copy` to avoid re-encoding a video, the stream can only be trimmed on a key picture.  If the second key picture in the bit stream occurs after the 4 second mark, the trim point is "rounded down" to the first key picture.

You'll either need to live with that, or re-encode the video (i.e. don't use the `-c copy` option).

**Added by barlop**

This is correct, and if one looks at the keyframes of the video

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18085458/checking-keyframe-interval

`ffprobe -loglevel error -select_streams v:0 -show_entries packet=pts_time,flags -of csv=print_section=0 input.mp4 | awk -F',' '/K/ {print $1}'`

(replacing input.mp4 with the filename, blah.mp4)

```
$ ffprobe -loglevel error -select_streams v:0 -show_entries packet=pts_time,flags -of csv=print_section=0 blah.mp4 | awk -F',' '/K/ {print $1}'
0.000000
5.120000
8.520000
10.240000
14.440000
15.360000

user@hp-probook1 ~/blah
$
```

And see it can cut six seconds in, if copying codecs.

Doing `ffmpeg -ss 6 -i blah.mp4 -c copy test.mp4` on the 18sec file, then `mediainfo test.mp4 | find "Dur"`  shows that the new file is 13sec

But it won't cut 4 seconds in because the last keyframe at or before 4 seconds, is at 0 seconds.

The following works though

```
C:\blah>mediainfo blah.mp4 | find "Dur"
Duration                                 : 18 s 693 ms
Duration                                 : 18 s 680 ms
Duration                                 : 18 s 693 ms

C:\blah>
C:\blah>ffmpeg -ss 4 -i blah.mp4 -acodec libmp3lame -vcodec libx264 tt.mp4

C:\blah>mediainfo tt.mp4 | find "Dur"
Duration                                 : 14 s 718 ms
Duration                                 : 14 s 680 ms
Duration                                 : 14 s 718 ms
Duration_LastFrame                       : -16 ms

C:\blah>

(I re-encoded the audio too, otherwise I got 18s audio and 14s video)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your are telling it to chop a bit off **and** copy the whole video; try

```
ffmpeg -ss 4 -i /tmp/blah.mp4  /tmp/blah2.mp4
```

Comment: without specifying whether to copy or to reencode, then it would just reencode with default codecs which isn't generally recommended but I suppose it would work. I have used `-vcodec libx264` and `-acodec libmp3lame`  I have heard that thse days the default codecs for mp4 are pretty good

Comment: You write "Your are telling it to chop a bit off and copy the whole video" <-- I don't think so. I think i'm telling it to chop a bit off and copy the rest of the video.  It will if chopping 6 seconds off, but it won't if trying to chop 4 seconds off. And that's because of keyframes in the video. Also I think one only needs to reencode the video, but with audio one can copy it. e.g. `-vcodec libx264 -acodec copy`

Comment: OK - I accept my answer is wrong, but for the quality of sample given, I doubt you would notice the effect the default codecs.

Comment: I didn't say your answer was wrong. I just mentioned certain issues with it. Where you wrote "the whole video"  you should change that to "the rest of the video".  Your description is trying to suggest that my example is undoing the "chopping off" and that's not true.